# Debugger doesn't work out of a sudden in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, macos, debugging, pycharm

I'm using:

```
PyCharm 2016.1.4 Build #PY-145.1504, built on May 25, 2016 JRE:
1.8.0_76-release-b198 x86_64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

On a mac:

```
OSX El Capitan
Version 10.11.4
```

Without having made any changes to my code, I haven't been able to start the debugger anymore. I'm still able to use Run without any problem.

Also the debugger doesn't work if I just run it from the terminal with:

```
/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 54596 --file /Users/Vandborg/dev/dowant/dowant/manage.py runserver
```

It throws an unhandled excetions which can be seen here:

```
/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 54596 --file /Users/Vandborg/dev/dowant/dowant/manage.py runserver
pydev debugger: process 10046 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 145.1504)
pydev debugger: process 10055 is connecting

Validating models...
Unhandled exception in thread started by <_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace instance at 0x107455248>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 553, in __call__
    return self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 48, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Vandborg/dev/dowant/dowant/apps/box_helicom/models.py", line 161, in <module>
    class MessageHelicom(models.Model):
  File "/Users/Vandborg/dev/dowant/dowant/apps/box_helicom/models.py", line 178, in MessageHelicom
    from dowant.cart.models import Order
  File "/Users/Vandborg/dev/dowant/dowant/cart/models.py", line 44, in <module>
    from dowant.cart.tasks import backend_cache, order_status
  File "/Users/Vandborg/dev/dowant/dowant/cart/tasks/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from backend_cache import refresh_order_backend_cache
  File "/Users/Vandborg/dev/dowant/dowant/cart/tasks/backend_cache.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dowant.backend.models import OrderBackendCache
  File "/Users/Vandborg/dev/dowant/dowant/backend/models.py", line 18, in <module>
    from dowant.backend.tooltips import (tr_class_template,
  File "/Users/Vandborg/dev/dowant/dowant/backend/tooltips.py", line 53, in <module>
    '{% load localization %}'
  File "/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 186, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 282, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/Users/Vandborg/.virtualenvs/hungry/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 928, in load
    (taglib, e))
django.template.TemplateSyntaxError: 'localization' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading dowant.templatetags.localization: cannot import name helper_evalifnotquoted
```

The code in dowant.templatetags.localization haven't been touched in years. And well it is able to run, it's just doing this when I try to use it with the debugger.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an issue with pycharm, looks more like an issue with your own template tag and whatever `helper_evalifnotquoted` is

Comment: Yeah one would think. But since it's not a issue when I just use Run. Also that part of the code haven't been touched for years. And again I didn't change any code. It just happend from one day to another. Also I have a colleague running the same version of PyCharm, same code base, and he have no issue of running the debugger. :/

Answer (score 0):

Disregard. I found the issue, there was a difference in which order stuff was loaded with debug and run, and therefore helper_evalifnotquoted couldn't be resolved.